# C# How To Quit From Foreach Looping in WFA

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Im new in C# programming. I tried to delete checked row in datagridview. This is my application form:

[image]

And this is my button Delete code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    object obt = row.Cells["select"].Value;
                    if ((String)obt == "yes")
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item ?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            sqlCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM BARANG WHERE kode_barang = '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
                            sqlConnection1.Open();
                            sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            sqlConnection1.Close();
                        }
                        else if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item ?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }




            dataSet11.barang.Clear();
            sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);
        }
```

I was able to delete single data in the datagridview also inside the database by checked the checkbox and click delete button. Before the data deleted. The program will shows a YesNo messageBox. But when i tried to delete multiple row from gridview. Program will show messageBox until 3 times (the number of checkbox i checked). My question is how to delete multiple rows just by showing one messagebox. So when i delete multiple rows, i just need to click yes in the message box in once.

Comment: put MessageBox code outside loop

Comment: @EhsanSajjad
tried. but when i put message box code outside the loop. i cant set the value of "no" button. so the program will delete data though i click "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try a different approach like this:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item ?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            sqlCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM BARANG WHERE kode_barang = '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
            sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
```

Datagridview provides functionality to get selected rows. You can also edit a datagridview so it is only allowed to select rows.
Further more it's not necasarry to opem the connection every time.

If you really wanna stick to your approach you could use `break;`to exit your loop.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Vincenz can you help me one more time ?
I want to  create messagebox that tell user to check at least one row before clicked delete button. Can you tell me the pseudecode ?
i want try it my self, so just tell me the steps. Dont shows me the code.

Comment: If you want to check that a row is clicked before the delete button is pressed I would advise you to enable the delete button or make it with a messagebox. It would off course be smoother if you would just enable and disable the button because then the failure can not even appear at all. 
I would disable the button by default and add a rowselectlistener to the datagridview. In the row select listener I would enable the button when it is selected. When you want to do it with a msgbox you should just check if dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count is bigger then 0 when no show to msg box

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, where it will prompt once and delete all rows.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var rowsRemoved = dataGridView1.Rows.Where(x => x.Cells["select"].Value == "yes");

    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete " + rowsRemoved.Count() + " items ?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in rowsRemoved)
        {
                sqlCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM BARANG WHERE kode_barang = '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
                sqlConnection1.Open();
                sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }

   dataSet11.barang.Clear();
   sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);
}
```

Comment: if zero rows found it will still prompt

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Neither here nor there. It doesn't do anything when 0 rows are selected. If you can point me to that requirement in the post by all means.

Comment: it will, you are not checking if 0 records retunred we will still see Message Box that are you sure you want to delete 0 records

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Obviously. I meant it would not delete anything. If we spent our time worrying about someone else's nice to haves, you 'd never get an answer written on SO.